# How to add multiple categories in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2.3 and Mongoid

I try to add multiple categories.

category.rb

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :tickets
  belongs_to :user
end
```

ticket.rb

```
class Ticket
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
end
```

tickets/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@ticket, html: { role: 'form' }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :title, options = { include_hidden: false }, html_options = { multiple: true } %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to save gives an error that the "Category can't be blank"

log

> Processing by TicketsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"rZyRkTPqTdM//ymnKGsm4Ctm5Co7YgAnSQg6oOaOVv4qEua1QB6cxclId2H4lm1rHG49H/2KomLWab1FaKnf1g==",
>   "ticket"=>{"name"=>"test", "description"=>"test",
>   "category_id"=>["5d0939d51996da62c1bd4699",
>   "5d0939de1996da62c1bd469a"]}, "commit"=>"Save"} MONGODB |
>   localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | STARTED |
>   {"find"=>"users",
>   "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d77b34d1996da1a261c111d')},
>   "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true,
>   "lsid"=>{"id"=>}} MONGODB | localhost:27017 |
>   remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.002s MONGODB |
>   localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | STARTED |
>   {"find"=>"categories",
>   "filter"=>{"_id"=>[BSON::ObjectId('5d0939d51996da62c1bd4699'),
>   BSON::ObjectId('5d0939de1996da62c1bd469a')]}, "limit"=>1,
>   "singleBatch"=>true, "lsid"=>{"id"=>}} MONGODB | localhost:27017 |
>   remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.003s   Rendering
>   tickets/new.html.erb within layouts/application   Rendered
>   shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.9ms) MONGODB | localhost:27017 |
>   remotely_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"categories",
>   "filter"=>{}, "lsid"=>{"id"=>}} MONGODB | localhost:27017 |
>   remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s   Rendered
>   tickets/_form.html.erb (9.7ms)   Rendered tickets/new.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (12.9ms)   Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (1.9ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 120ms (Views: 104.9ms | MongoDB: 0.0ms)

Comment: Please check if you have added the same in strong_params

Comment: `params.require(:ticket).permit(category_id: [])`

Comment: At first glance this looks fine. So, it must working. What happens if it isn't ?, something must be wrong, right ?, and the code you share is not enough to guess what's happening. It'd be good if you add your request logs, part of the code in the controller that does the update(or if you use a form object, share that part then), also share how you have your associations in your models, etc.

Comment: @fanta Yes, something is wrong. I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 2 ids to a `belongs_to` association with name `category_id`. You actually need a `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#has-and-belongs-to-many so it's a multiple relationship and the attribute will be `category_ids` in plural.